# parameters of a distribution are constant but not a variable? Why

Tags: random-variable, variable

For example, the standard deviation of a normal distribution is a constant? Why is that?

Comment: What's your own background on the problem? When I asked a similar question in my undergraduate stats class, my professor accused me of being an "improperly trained Bayesian".

Comment: Briefly a random variable *can* be a constant - it takes one value with probability 1. Parameters of a distribution are equivalently defined according to the SLLN: the mean of the distribution is what you get when $n \rightarrow \infty$, you can for instance defined $\mu = E[\bar{X}]$, which is a useful consideration for Bayesian asymptotics.

Comment: If I understand correctly, from the Bayesian point of view, the parameter we are trying to estimate is a random variable and has its distribution, right? We have usually a prior about its distribution and a posterior after observation. So I always assume the parameter is a random variable. But today, I read from a finance textbook that the standard deviation from a distribution is a constant, but not a variable (note that they didn't say random variable), which makes me quite confused.

Comment: See [this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=distribution+family+statistical+model+parameter+frequent*+is%3Aanswer+score%3A5).  (This is a highly refined search because thousands of posts here on CV refer to model parameters.)